# Multiple display stopped working - log understanding

Tags: display, syslog, thunderbolt, displaylink

The secondary displays on my XPS 7390 have suddenly stopped working. The laptop is attached to a docking station and uses displayLink. I don't see anymore the displays in the settings. The other devices connected to the docking station work fine.

I have these logs repeating over and over again:

```
Jan 15 16:29:00 karl-XPS-13-KDE systemd[1]: Failed to start DisplayLink Driver Service.
Jan 15 16:29:02 karl-XPS-13-KDE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2337]: JavaScript error: resource:///modules/activity/autosync.jsm, line 251: uncaught exception: 2147746065
Jan 15 16:29:04 karl-XPS-13-KDE kernel: [  122.578082] thunderbolt 0000:05:00.0: control channel starting...
Jan 15 16:29:04 karl-XPS-13-KDE kernel: [  122.578092] thunderbolt 0000:05:00.0: starting TX ring 0
Jan 15 16:29:04 karl-XPS-13-KDE kernel: [  122.578107] thunderbolt 0000:05:00.0: enabling interrupt at register 0x38200 bit 0 (0x0 -> 0x1)
Jan 15 16:29:04 karl-XPS-13-KDE kernel: [  122.578112] thunderbolt 0000:05:00.0: starting RX ring 0
Jan 15 16:29:04 karl-XPS-13-KDE kernel: [  122.578126] thunderbolt 0000:05:00.0: enabling interrupt at register 0x38200 bit 12 (0x1 -> 0x1001)
Jan 15 16:29:04 karl-XPS-13-KDE kernel: [  122.770721] cdc_ncm 4-2.1:1.5 enx0050b6e8c275: 1000 mbit/s downlink 1000 mbit/s uplink
Jan 15 16:29:04 karl-XPS-13-KDE kernel: [  122.802711] cdc_ncm 4-2.1:1.5 enx0050b6e8c275: network connection: connected
Jan 15 16:29:05 karl-XPS-13-KDE systemd[1]: displaylink-driver.service: Service RestartSec=5s expired, scheduling restart.
Jan 15 16:29:05 karl-XPS-13-KDE systemd[1]: displaylink-driver.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 22.
Jan 15 16:29:05 karl-XPS-13-KDE systemd[1]: Stopped DisplayLink Driver Service.
Jan 15 16:29:05 karl-XPS-13-KDE systemd[1]: Starting DisplayLink Driver Service...
Jan 15 16:29:05 karl-XPS-13-KDE kernel: [  123.750563] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
Jan 15 16:29:05 karl-XPS-13-KDE kernel: [  123.753112] module: x86/modules: Skipping invalid relocation target, existing value is nonzero for type 1, loc 0000000094e642c4, val ffffffffc0d5b9ef
Jan 15 16:29:05 karl-XPS-13-KDE sh[7532]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'evdi': Exec format error
Jan 15 16:29:05 karl-XPS-13-KDE sh[7532]: Module evdi/5.2.14 already installed on kernel 4.15.0-1066-oem/x86_64
Jan 15 16:29:05 karl-XPS-13-KDE kernel: [  123.894477] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
Jan 15 16:29:05 karl-XPS-13-KDE kernel: [  123.896415] module: x86/modules: Skipping invalid relocation target, existing value is nonzero for type 1, loc 0000000026af26df, val ffffffffc0d729ef
Jan 15 16:29:05 karl-XPS-13-KDE sh[7532]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'evdi': Exec format error
Jan 15 16:29:05 karl-XPS-13-KDE systemd[1]: displaylink-driver.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 15 16:29:05 karl-XPS-13-KDE systemd[1]: displaylink-driver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 15 16:29:05 karl-XPS-13-KDE systemd[1]: Failed to start DisplayLink Driver Service.
Jan 15 16:29:10 karl-XPS-13-KDE systemd[1]: displaylink-driver.service: Service RestartSec=5s expired, scheduling restart.
Jan 15 16:29:10 karl-XPS-13-KDE systemd[1]: displaylink-driver.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 23.
Jan 15 16:29:10 karl-XPS-13-KDE systemd[1]: Stopped DisplayLink Driver Service.
Jan 15 16:29:10 karl-XPS-13-KDE systemd[1]: Starting DisplayLink Driver Service...
Jan 15 16:29:10 karl-XPS-13-KDE kernel: [  129.002964] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
Jan 15 16:29:10 karl-XPS-13-KDE kernel: [  129.005748] module: x86/modules: Skipping invalid relocation target, existing value is nonzero for type 1, loc 0000000069cc8c8e, val ffffffffc0d899ef
Jan 15 16:29:10 karl-XPS-13-KDE sh[7638]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'evdi': Exec format error
Jan 15 16:29:10 karl-XPS-13-KDE sh[7638]: Module evdi/5.2.14 already installed on kernel 4.15.0-1066-oem/x86_64
Jan 15 16:29:10 karl-XPS-13-KDE kernel: [  129.140629] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
Jan 15 16:29:10 karl-XPS-13-KDE kernel: [  129.141606] module: x86/modules: Skipping invalid relocation target, existing value is nonzero for type 1, loc 0000000030fb221b, val ffffffffc0da09ef
Jan 15 16:29:10 karl-XPS-13-KDE sh[7638]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'evdi': Exec format error
Jan 15 16:29:10 karl-XPS-13-KDE systemd[1]: displaylink-driver.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 15 16:29:10 karl-XPS-13-KDE systemd[1]: displaylink-driver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 15 16:29:10 karl-XPS-13-KDE systemd[1]: Failed to start DisplayLink Driver Service.
Jan 15 16:29:15 karl-XPS-13-KDE systemd[1]: displaylink-driver.service: Service RestartSec=5s expired, scheduling restart.
Jan 15 16:29:15 karl-XPS-13-KDE systemd[1]: displaylink-driver.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 24.
Jan 15 16:29:15 karl-XPS-13-KDE systemd[1]: Stopped DisplayLink Driver Service.
Jan 15 16:29:15 karl-XPS-13-KDE systemd[1]: Starting DisplayLink Driver Service...
Jan 15 16:29:15 karl-XPS-13-KDE kernel: [  134.250707] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
Jan 15 16:29:15 karl-XPS-13-KDE kernel: [  134.253518] module: x86/modules: Skipping invalid relocation target, existing value is nonzero for type 1, loc 00000000e755cdc9, val ffffffffc0db79ef
Jan 15 16:29:15 karl-XPS-13-KDE sh[7741]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'evdi': Exec format error
Jan 15 16:29:15 karl-XPS-13-KDE sh[7741]: Module evdi/5.2.14 already installed on kernel 4.15.0-1066-oem/x86_64
Jan 15 16:29:15 karl-XPS-13-KDE kernel: [  134.392079] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
Jan 15 16:29:15 karl-XPS-13-KDE kernel: [  134.393027] module: x86/modules: Skipping invalid relocation target, existing value is nonzero for type 1, loc 00000000ae8c9579, val ffffffffc0dce9ef
Jan 15 16:29:15 karl-XPS-13-KDE sh[7741]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'evdi': Exec format error
Jan 15 16:29:15 karl-XPS-13-KDE systemd[1]: displaylink-driver.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 15 16:29:15 karl-XPS-13-KDE systemd[1]: displaylink-driver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 15 16:29:15 karl-XPS-13-KDE systemd[1]: Failed to start DisplayLink Driver Service.
```

Can anyone tell me if it seems hardware related or if there is any command/debugging I could do?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic linux-firmware
reboot
```

And it resolved the problem